# Qt-creator publish tab missing click part

Tags: application-development, packaging, qt, qt-creator

I am trying step by step to write some simple tutorial Ubuntu apps using qt-creator. First I've chosen HTML5 App then after writing some hello code or even after doing nothing I've tried to create a package so I've tried to follow http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/packaging-click-apps/ but my creator lacks this click part it just starts with validation. Am I missing something here ? Or maybe I've selected wrong kit (Ubuntu SDK for i386)?